# Firebase authentication flow with Expo + react navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm trying to set up Firebase authentication in Expo using React Navigation v5 and running into some difficulty. Based on what I have read, I am trying to set up navigation within my App.js as follows:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user != null) {
        setUser(user);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    {isLoading ? (
      <LoadingScreen />
    ) : user ? (
      <MainTabScreen />
    ) : (
      <AuthStackScreen />
    )}
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

where `LoadingScreen` displays an ActivityIndicator, `MainTabScreen` returns a tab navigator containing the main app, and `AuthStackScreen` returns a stack navigator with sign in and sign up screens. Currently I'm getting an error `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`, but I suspect that there is a deeper issue with my current auth navigation flow.

Could anyone provide any resources outlining how to implement this basic flow using Firebase, React Navigation 5, and Expo?

Comment: Is your loading screen hiding and authstack or maintabscreen showing up??

Comment: Where does the error point at

Comment: Currently I'm just getting `Error: Invalid hook call` when I try to run the app - is there something wrong with my `useEffect` hook?

Comment: Same here. Still working on it.